# If a battery has a date of manufacture stamp of 2016 on it and will not charge, is it expired? Yuasa NP17-12L. I think I’m being conned. Help!

Tags: electrical, battery

I have recently had a dispute over a battery which would not work for longer than 5 mins. The battery is a Yuasa NP7-12L. The date stamp says manufactured in 2016. Is this out of date? Please help guys. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. There's not enough information in your question. Was this battery sold to you as new, or has it been in your car for some time? What is the issue you are having?

Comment: If the date is the date of manufacture, then the battery is too old to depend upon.

Comment: A Yuasa NP7-12L surely isn't a battery used on a vehicle, is it?  It looks more like something you would find in a house alarm or a stair lift from my experience.

Comment: Are you talking about a car battery? What is this battery for?

Comment: Just noticed that you have different batteries specified in the title to the main body.  Is it a NP7-12L or a NP17-12L.  Presumably the NP17-12L could be a motorbike battery.

Answer (score 1):

If a Sealed lead-acid starter battery was sitting around on a shelf for 6 years and never used or maintained, it could be dead.  Symptom would be that it shows ~13V or so, but any load and it just has no runtime.  A 12V lightbulb would go visibly dim very quickly.

If the battery had a "maintenance" or trickle charge every 1-3 months it might still be okay.  This would be something a good store would do to their stock.

---

A battery that has been in your car for 6 years might be workable, but they're often dead after ~4 winters, and maybe less if you store the car outside.   Symptoms are flakey and hard starting, then a jumpstart gets you going.  Restarts throughout the day are okay, but the next morning it struggles again.  This is a dead battery and it needs replacing with a new one.

A ridiculously-oversized starter battery can last a decade easily in a car.

---

Can you add more information to your question?

Answer (score 1):

A run-of-the-mill "lead acid" car battery?   Yes, a 6-year-old *lead-acid* is pretty much at the end of its service life, unless it was stored "dry" with the acid out of it.  The acid is destructive to the battery no matter how it's used.

Any performance you get past 6 years is sheer luck.

Experts view the short life as a worthwhile trade-off for the very low cost of lead-acid batteries.  A comparable battery of a different technology would be 5 times the price (but would last 20 years).  Even if you kept the car 20 years, you'd be money ahead doing 3 replacement of lead-acid.  And the vast majority of cars are not kept by the owner for 20 years.